# Can I define functions and global variables within debian rules make file?

Tags: debian, package-management, make

Can I define functions and global variables within a debian `rules` make file, to be used within the different `override_****` sections ?

Have not had success in doing so.

For example, the following is an excerpt of one of my script files. I would like to use this function and global variables within my debian rules file as well, throughout the override sections.

```
# console output colors
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
RED='\033[1;31m'
BLUE='\033[1;34m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'

#return code
rc=999

######################### Functions #############################
function logCommandExecution()
{
    commandName=$1
    exitCode=$2
    #echo 'command name: '${commandName}' exitCode: '${exitCode}
    if [ ${exitCode} -eq 0 ] 
    then
        printf "${GREEN}${commandName}' completed successfully${NC}\n"
    else 
        printf "${RED}${commandName} failed with error code [${exitCode}]${NC}\n"
        exit ${exitCode}
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `debian/rules` file is a makefile, not a sh file.

I stuck your function into a makefile to try it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# console output colors
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
RED='\033[1;31m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'

######################### Functions #############################
function logCommandExecution()
{
    commandName=$1
    exitCode=$2
    #echo 'command name: '${commandName}' exitCode: '${exitCode}
    if [ ${exitCode} -eq 0 ] 
    then
        printf "${GREEN}${commandName}' completed successfully${NC}\n"
    else 
        printf "${RED}${commandName} failed with error code [${exitCode}]${NC}\n"
        exit ${exitCode}
    fi
}


all:
        logCommandExecution Passcmd 0
        logCommandExecution Failcmd 1
```

Then wehen I try to execute this I get:

```
$ make all
makefile:14: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

So the answer is not directly.  However there are some ways to run shell syntax in makefiles.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574592/1723954) might help with that.

I think the easiest way is to put the function in another file, and call it from `debian/rules`:

makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
all:
        ./logCommandExecution Passcmd 0
        ./logCommandExecution Failcmd 1
```

logCommandExecution:

```
#!/bin/sh

# console output colors
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
RED='\033[1;31m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'

commandName=$1
exitCode=$2
#echo 'command name: '${commandName}' exitCode: '${exitCode}
if [ ${exitCode} -eq 0 ] 
then
    printf "${GREEN}${commandName}' completed successfully${NC}\n"
else 
    printf "${RED}${commandName} failed with error code [${exitCode}]${NC}\n"
    exit ${exitCode}
fi
```

Now when I make it, I get:

```
$ make
./logCommandExecution Passcmd 0
Passcmd' completed successfully
./logCommandExecution Failcmd 1
Failcmd failed with error code [1]
make: *** [makefile:5: all] Error 1
```

Comment: Hey Stewart, thanks for that bit. I will look into what you suggest.